# how to pass in variables over CLI when running cdktf deploy

Tags: terraform, terraform-cdk

I currently have a cdktf (terraform cdk for typescript) project where I have a variable defined as follows:

```
const resourceName = new TerraformVariable(this, "resourceName", {
      type: "string",
      default: "defaultResourceName",
      description: "resource name",
});
```

However, when I run `cdktf deploy -var="resourceName=foo"` I am seeing that the `resourceName` variable is still `defaultResourceName` rather than `foo` as I have intended to pass in via the cli. According to the terraform documentation at https://www.terraform.io/language/values/variables#variables-on-the-command-line this is the right way to pass in variables on the cli but it's clearly not working here - would anyone know the actual correct way? I know variables can be dynamically changed via environment variables but I'd ideally like to just pass variables through cli directly.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to set `EXCLUDE_STACK_ID_FROM_LOGICAL_IDS` to true in the cdktf.json file, otherwise, the variables get a random suffix.

Also, there's no `-var` flag for the [deploy argument](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cdktf/cli-reference/commands#deploy), you have to set them as [environment variables](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/config/environment-variables#tf_var_name).

Comment: `--var` is a documented arg (it's in the^ link you share). 

@sabo note at least on macos its `--var` (the hyphens) not `-var` (one hyphen). Maybe you are on Windows.

Answer (score -1):

I used `cdktf deploy -p resourceName=foo`

Comment: what version of cdktf are you using?

Comment: I've never seen this -p option anywhere before, and it's still not working for me